# Writing an if-not-null procedure

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I often see the following pattern in my code where I have to ignore the empty-sequence:

```
#lang sicp
(define (map func sequence)
  (if (null? sequence) nil
      (cons (func (car sequence)) (map func (cdr sequence)))))
(map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3))
; (2 3 4)
```

I would like to create a function that basically handles that on its own as a special-case form of the `if`, something like:

```
; if not null...
(if-nn (cons (func (car sequence)) (map func (cdr sequence))))))
```

Here is what I have come up with so far, though it doesn't seem to save much, so I'm hoping there may be a better way to do it...

```
(define (if-nn sequence func)
  (if (null? sequence) nil func))

(define (map2 func sequence)
  (if-nn sequence (cons (func (car sequence)) (map func (cdr sequence)))))

(map2 (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) '(1 2 3))
; (2 3 4)
```

I suppose a more general-purpose one would be something like this that allows for a specific default value:

```
(define (ifnull default sequence func)
  (if (null? sequence) default func))
```

What would be the proper way to write this?

---

I think there may be an issue with application order here as well because the following does not work:

```
(define (if-nn sequence function)
  (if (not (null? sequence)) function))

(define (map3 func sequence)
  (if-nn 
      (cons (func (car sequence)) (map3 func (cdr sequence)))))

(map3 list '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

But doing the literal substitution of `(if-nn`  with `(if (not (null? sequence))` works fine. I suppose for this these would need to be something like delayed evaluation in order for that to work.

Comment: Are you familiar with `not`?

Comment: @Shawn sort of...Is it just as simple as `(define (if-nn seq fun) (if (not (null? seq)) func))` ?

Comment: @Shawn actually, I think it may be a problem because of application-order...

Comment: Yup, that simple. Some schemes (Not sure about Racket) have an `unless` form that can be used too. `(unless test body)` that only executes body if the test is false.

Comment: However, I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do... any recursive implementation of `map` needs to deal with an empty list as its base case. Might as well use your first version unless you're trying for a tail recursive one. But a macro instead of a function would be one thing to investigate.

Comment: Racket does have `unless`. However if the body doesn't run, it returns `#<void>`, which is different from null.  (null and '() are identical in vanilla Racket.)

Comment: Also @David542, functions in Racket take values. What you're trying to do is create new syntax in Racket, which would be done with `define-syntax`. In this case, it seems like you're trying to create syntax for a maybe monad. If you are okay with using `#<void>` instead of `null`, then `unless`/`when` work. Likewise, if you're okay with using `false` instead of `null`, then `and`/`or` work. If you do really need it to return null in particular, then its probably best to make a macro.

Comment: (if that is what you need we can show you how to do that easily enough. I just want to make sure its actually what you need first. ;) )

Comment: @LeifAndersen either one is fine really (null or void or false), I was just curious how that might be done and/or how it might be possible to get around the application order stuff so the `sequence` isn't run before the test.

Comment: functions evaluate their argument expressions before starting their work with the values; macros receive their argument expressions as code AST and manipulate those pieces of code, building and returning the new code which then runs.